# Question on Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff (TOV) equation for time-dependent spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, metric-tensor, symmetry

Is there a way to conceive a [TOV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation), and therefore the stability analysis for a metric like:

$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + a^2(t,r)\big(dr^2 + r^2d\Omega ^2\big)~?\tag{1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The [TOV equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69953/226902) apply when you have a static, spherically symmetric spacetime (they describe the hydrostatic equilibrium): they are derived from the Einstein equations under the assumption of [static spherical spacetime and perfect fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spherically_symmetric_perfect_fluid), see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760425/226902).

If the body is [collapsing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/733292/226902) /exploding /oscillating in a spherically symmetric way, you need to consider the full Einstein equations (they simplify a lot because of spherical symmetry) and provide a model for matter (the simplest possibility is the perfect fluid, like for the TOV). You can find a scheme in [Simple equations for general relativistic hydrodynamics in spherical symmetry applied to neutron star collapse](http://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1991A&A...252..651G/abstract). Another scheme is, e.g., the one implemented in the one-dimensional, general-relativistic hydrodynamic code (publicly available) developed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.11810). A simpler case was studied by Snyder and Oppenheimer: calculated the gravitational [collapse of a pressure-free sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226673/226902) of dust particles as described by general relativity.

**Edit**: I notice now that maybe you are more interested in a [FLRW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) spacetime, while the links in my answer are for a Schwarzschild-like metric (like the one of a non-rotating neutron star/white dwarf).  I am a bit confused on what exactly you are looking for. However, the general comments are still valid: you just have to provide a matter model (I.e. an energy-momentum tensor) and write explicitly Einstein equations for you metric ansatz.